# WPF: ICollectionView - Filter one list if item is contained in another list?

Tags: wpf, listview, filter, itemssource, icollectionview

Basically, I have 2 ListView's each binding to a different `ItemsSource`.

List 1 **can not** be changed (it's a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`).
List 2 **can** be changed (through user interaction).

I need to add a filter to List 1 so that it doesn't display anything that's found in List 2. This is my code so far...

```
view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List1.ItemsSource);
view.Filter += o =>
{
    MyItem item = o as MyItem;
    return List2.ItemsSource.??;
};
```

---

List2.ItemsSource comes back as an IEnumerable instead of ObservableCollection (what it really is). I want to do this as efficiently as possible, so I wasn't sure if I should:

1. Explicitly Cast the ItemsSource as a IList to gain access to Contains?
2. Iterate through the the ItemsSource myself to see if it contains the item?
3. Use LINQ's Cast extension method to cast to an IList (or some other type) to gain access to Contains?
4. Any other way?

---

**UPDATE:**

It doesn't seem to continue filtering items after the first time it renders:

```
view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List1.ItemsSource);
view.Filter += o =>
{
    MyItem item = (MyItem)o;
    var collection = (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)List2.ItemsSource;
    //return collection.Contains(item);//Filters out ALL items from the list
    return !collection.Contains(item); //Shows all items, but as I add items
                                       //to list 2 it doesn't filter items out of
                                       //list 1.
};
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I think I understand why it's not reapplying the filter. The original collection is not raising a CollectionChanged notification, so it doesn't bother to run the filter again. Perhaps solving this part is better suited as a different question? But, in case anyone wants to answer it here:

How can I get my List1 to reapply the filter when the List2 collection changes?

**UPDATE 3:**
I asked how to tie into the collectionchanged event in a [separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806172/wpf-how-do-i-hook-into-a-listviews-collectionchanged-notification) and got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemsSource` is statically declared as an `IEnumerable`, but its actual runtime type can be anything that implements `IEnumerable`. If you happen to know that it's actually an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`, you can just cast to this type:

```
view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List1.ItemsSource);
view.Filter += o =>
{
    MyItem item = (MyItem)o;
    var collection = (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)List2.ItemsSource;
    return collection.Contains(item);
};
```

(or you can just cast to `IList<MyItem>`, since `Contains` is defined in this interface)

Linq is also a good option:

```
view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List1.ItemsSource);
view.Filter += o =>
{
    MyItem item = (MyItem)o;
    return List2.ItemsSource.Cast<MyItem>().Contains(item);
};
```

Comment: Yes, both seem to work properly, but moreover I was hoping to know which was the best (most efficient).

Comment: Actually, I just ran it, I thought they were running properly but it doesn't seem to be filtering. A lot of items were closely named so I thought they were being filtered out, but it isn't...

Comment: @michael, none is really better than the other, since it will always end up doing a linear search on List2. The first option (cast) is probably slightly faster than the second (Linq .Cast/.Contains), but probably not noticeably

Comment: The filter won't refresh automatically when List2 is modified. You need to reassign the Filter property of the ICollectionView to reexecute the filter explicitly.

Comment: @Thomas: How would one be able to do that?