# WPF, DataGrid, same sorting applied after ItemsSource changed

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have `DataGrid`. It's `ItemsSource` property changes from one `List1<SameClass>` to another `List2<SameClass>`.

User selects a column and direction of sorting data on the `DataGrid`.

Then user switches `ItemsSource` property -> the sorting disappears.

I want to apply the same sorting after user changes `ItemsSource` property.

I guess I need to remember sorting, change `ItemsSource` property and apply remembered sorting.

But how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code? From what I see, you can make a function that sorts whatever list you pass into and call that function every time `ItemsSource` changes. But instead of changing the `ItemsSource`, maybe changing the contents of the **List** itself may be a better idea since you can raise the `OnPropertiesChanged` event.

Comment: @Zinthos The thing about this task is that I am amending the code by adding this functionality. It would be easier for me not to change the way it works internally, just make sure that sorting is kept after `ItemsSource` changes.

Comment: @Zinthos In other words I need to (a) Find out what is current sorting order of `DataGrid` (b) Save this information to some kind of variable (c) apply this sorting order again on `DataGrid` after `ItemsSource` property has been changed.

Comment: Sorry I have never done it like that before. But these links may help : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806172/wpf-how-do-i-hook-into-a-listviews-itemssource-collectionchanged-notification)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708806/how-to-raise-an-event-when-datagrid-itemssource-is-changed)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534075/what-triggers-ui-to-update-when-itemscontrol-itemssource-changed)

Comment: @Zinthos thank you mate, I gave up and did the whole thing the way it is supposed to be made: using ObservableCollection